# Word 97 does not let me create macros unless I run in compatibility mode, but then opening files from explorer stops working

Tags: vba, ms-word

So I wanted to make a message box appear saying a nice and funny message as a joke in Word 97, and yes, I know it's old, I just have an interest to old stuff. But when I hit create, it just says "The macro couldn't be created." Upon running it with compatibility mode, I used Windows 98/ME, and the macros started working but the program became very unstable. Not only that, but opening a word document through explorer would not work. I'm using Windows 7. Can anyone help me?

I tried running in compatibility mode, didn't work as expected.

Comment: Old software usually requires old operating systems and old computers to run them.